# Symfony get and set property in same controller?

Tags: database, symfony, orm

i'm trying to add 1 year on a date in symfony, so i did:

```
#[Route(path: ['en' => '/upd', 'it' => '/upd'], name: 'upd')]
public function upd(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
{
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $domain =  $em->getRepository(Domain::class)->find(473);

    $domain->setPaymentDueDate(
        $domain->getPaymentDueDate()->modify('+ 365 day')
    );

    $em->persist($domain);
    $em->flush();
}
```

But it is still the same date, no changes.
If i use another get from the same entity, like this

```
$domain->setPaymentDueDate(
            $domain->getCreationDate()->modify('+ 365 day')
        );
```

everything work ok. Also on the dump, after flush(), it show me the date with +365 days so i really don't know what is hapening.
GET and SET functions are symfony's default.

```
class Domain
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: 'domain.creation_date.not_blank')]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $creation_date = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $expiration_date = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface  $payment_due_date = null;
```

I noticed that in ptofiler->doctrine, where queries are shown, there is not "Update" query. But when get/set are for different attributes then i see the "update" query.

Comment: Is you date immutable ?

Comment: @DylanKAS nop, is Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE

Answer (score 1):

you can clone it maybe before set it again :

```
$domain->setPaymentDueDate(
    (clone $domain->getPaymentDueDate())->modify('+ 365 day')
);
```